# Chrome crashes computer when I insert USB Ethernet adapter

Tags: macos, google-chrome, crash

It seems that Chrome causes a crash on macOS whenever I insert a USB Ethernet adapter.

For a long time I didn't know the reason; I just plugged it in and tried it again and again until my Mac accepted it and let me use it. I thought it was just a problem with macOS.

But yesterday, I changed the default browser to Safari, and I was able to successfully use my adapter the whole day. At the end of the day I decided to make Chrome my default browser again, and my Mac crashed.

Today I experimented more and found that whenever I connect to the Internet via Ethernet, everything is OK until I open Chrome. I tried disabling all my plugins but it didn't help.

What can I do?

Comment: I edited your question for clarity; could you read it over and see if I misunderstood anything? Also, when you say you tried disabling your "plugins", do you mean your Chrome extensions?

Comment: Further information that would be helpful: What brand of adapter are you using, and what version of macOS and Chrome are you running? Does Chrome work with other network interfaces, such as Wi-Fi or tethered to your phone? If you could edit your question to include all this information, that would help a lot towards diagnosing your problem.

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.2 (16C67), 
USB 3.0 to 10/100/1000 Gigabit RJ45 Ethernet LAN Network Adapter 1000Mbps 
Chrome works perfectly with wifi and bluetooth tethering, the only problem is with this usb2lan cable,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the realtek drivers which cause the hang which the USB ethernet adaptor tries to use and Chrome seems to get mangled into it.  If you're running the latest Sierra you probably don't actually need these installed.  You can either remove them both through /library/extensions *RTL815* or run the scripted uninstaller that comes with the package from 
http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=55&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Comment: Thank you. I removed the drivers, and now it doesnt crash